# MVC 2 Pass View to Controller to generate Excel File on-the-fly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

Is there a way to pass data from a View to a Controller so that I can get the data and create a .xls file on the fly?

Any help or thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a [CSV file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), which can be opened directly by Excel.

Alternatively, you can use [COM Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(VS.80).aspx) to generate the Excel files.

The data is passed from the view to the controller method in the usual way.  If you need help getting a collection of rows from the view, have a look [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx).

The data is provided to the user by returning a [FileResult](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[ASP.NET MVC Tip #2 - Create a custom Action Result that returns Microsoft Excel Documents](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/06/16/asp-net-mvc-tip-2-create-a-custom-action-result-that-returns-microsoft-excel-documents.aspx)

How about this.